# How to refresh an HTML element quickly?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here, but I'm just trying to learn sockets/channels for dynamically pushing content from a server to a client. Here's my server side code that's pushing a random value once a second:

```
import datetime
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import json
import logging
from google.appengine.api import channel
import random
import time
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))

timestamp = unicode(datetime.datetime.now())
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.get('query'):
        # request to get data
            while True:
                random_num = random.randrange(80,90)
                logging.info(random_num)
                channel.send_message(timestamp,str(random_num))
                time.sleep(1)

        token = channel.create_channel(timestamp)
        context = {
            'token': token, 
        }
        template = template_env.get_template('home.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

Here's my HTML/javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="createConnection()">Create Connection</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="startStream()">Start Data Stream</button>
    <div id="connectionalive"></div>
    <div id="value"></div>
<script>
function createConnection() {
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
    socket = channel.open();
    //socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = displayData;
    //socket.onerror = onError;
    //socket.onclose = onClose;
    parseResponse()
}
function displayData(msg) {
    console.log("received message"); 
    $("#value").html("<p style='font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: red; font-size: 26px;'>"+msg.data+"</p>");
    }
function parseResponse() { 
        $("#connectionalive").html("<p style='font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black; font-size: 14px;'>Connection Alive</p>");
        }
function startStream() { 

    $.ajax('/', {
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        data: {
        query: 'startstream',
    }, 
    success: function() { logging.info("stream started") }
}); 

} 
</script>
</body>
```

The code is rough, I'm just trying to see that I can send a new value once a second and have it update on my website. However, when I click "Start Data Stream", my browser hangs and while it looks like my backend server is sending data through the channel, the browser doesn't update the `div`. When I stop the `while` loop, the browser updates, but just once.. it doesn't show a stream of values updating every second like I expected it to. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: i think it will call only once you need too use time for the calling again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a while loop in the code you posted, but if you're doing a while loop with synchronous ajax calls from the browser, then you are never giving the browser a chance to repaint.

A better implementation would be to configure your ajax call to be asynchronous, kick off the ajax call and then when it completes (e.g. calls the completion handler), you can update the page and fire off the next ajax call.  The page will then update during the asynchronous ajax call.

Busy loops and synchronous ajax calls are both bad things in a browser.  The browser MUST get back to its own event loop in order to repaint, respond to events and do other things that keep the browser responsive.  Code is usually repeated in a browser with either `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` which let you schedule some code to run some number of milliseconds into the future and during the time before that, the browser can handle it's own housekeeping (repaints, event processing, etc...).  In your case, you can already have a natural timing rhythm with an asynchronous ajax call.  Launch the async ajax call, return back to the event loop so the browser can do it's processing.  Then, when the completion function is triggered for the ajax call, you process the result and start the next ajax call.